# Testing multiple file upload to a model viewset using APIClient's post in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, tdd

I'm new to Test Driven Development and was trying to test an endpoint like so:

```
url = '/v3/edm-list/extract/'
c = APIClient()
c.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.token.key)
with open(test_email_list_path, 'rb') as eml, open(test_exclude_list_path, 'rb') as exl:
    data = {
        'tickers': tickers,
        'email_list': eml,
        'exlude_list': exl,
        'exclude_keywords': exclude_keywords,
        'simular_user_num': similar_user_num
    }
    response = c.post(url, data)

self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Using APIClient's post, I'm sending a post request to my model viewset:

```
class EDMListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EDMList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EDMListSerializer
```

With the model:

```
class EDMList(models.Model):
    tickers = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    email_list = models.FileField(upload_to='edm_list/consolidated_emails')
    exclude_list = models.FileField(upload_to='edm_list/excluded_emails')
    exclude_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    similar_user_num = models.IntegerField()
```

And serializer:

```
class EDMListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EDMList
        fields = ('tickers', 'email_list', 'exclude_list', 'exclude_keywords', 'similar_user_num')
```

Now whenever I run my tests, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

But whenever I open the browsable API, and post there, I runs correctly.
I'm guessing the problem is how I use the client's post, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try with multipart format? `c.post(url, data, format='multipart')`

Comment: @GabrielMuj Thank you responding! Unfortunately I've already tried this but it still results to status code 400.

Comment: I eventually finished my code, but I relapsed to not programming the TDD way. I still wanted to make this work, I just don't know how.

Comment: Can you print `response.data` for your 400  response

Answer (score 0):

I'm so ashamed to admit that it was a typographical error. From this:

```
data = {
            'exlude_list': exl,
            'simular_user_num': similar_user_num
        }
```

To this:

```
data = {
            'exclude_list': exl,
            'similar_user_num': similar_user_num
        }
```

Comment: It happens to all of us :)